# PostgreSQL calculate the top places per group and other statistics

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following structure

```
|user_id | place | type_of_place | money_earned| time |
|--------+-------+---------------+-------------+------|
|        |       |               |             |      |
```

The table is very large, several millions of rows. The data is in a PostgreSQL 9.1 database.

I want to calculate, per user_id and type_of_place: the mean, the standard deviation, and the top 5 of places (ordered by counts), and the most used hour of time (mode).

The resulting data must be in this form:

```
| user_id | type_of_place | avg | stddev |   top5_places    | mode |
+---------+---------------+-----+--------+------------------+------+
|     1   |      tp1      | 10  |   1    | {p1,p2,p3,p4,p5} |   8  |
|     2   |      tp1      |  3  |   2    | {p3,p4}          |   23 |
|     1   |      tp3      |  1  |   1    | {p1}             |   4  |
```

etc.

Is there a for of doing this with window functions efficiently?

What if I want to grouping by week? (i.e. another column that represents the number of week)

Thank you!

Comment: For `avg`, `stddev`; are these the average and std. dev. of the `money_earned` column?  And is the `top5_places` in ordered by `money_earned` from highest to least?  (I'm not sure what "ordered by counts" means.)

Comment: Thanks @Edmund, let me try to be more specific, what I tried to say "ordered by count" is that I want them ordered buy the times it appears, as a `count()`. So the first element in the array is the one that appears most, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard GROUP BY query will get you most of the way:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    type_of_place,
    avg(money_earned) AS avg,
    stddev(money_earned) AS stddev
FROM
    earnings  -- I'm not sure what your data table is called...
GROUP BY
    user_id,
    type_of_place
```

This leaves the `top5_places` and `mode` columns.  These are both also aggregates, but not ones which are defined in the standard PostgreSQL installation.  Luckily, you can add them.

Here's a page discussing how to define a `mode` aggregate function:  http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Mode

Once you have a `mode` aggregate function, assuming `time` is a timestamp of some kind, the expression you will add to the select list will be:

```
SELECT
    ...
    mode(extract(hour FROM time)) AS mode  -- Add this expression
FROM
    ...
```

**Assuming order by money**

For `top5_places`, there are several approaches, but the quickest is probably to use PostgreSQL's builtin `array_agg` function, and take the first 5 elements:

```
SELECT
    ...
    (array_agg(place ORDER BY money_earned DESC))[1:5] AS top5_places  -- Add this expression
FROM
    ...
```

One alternative is to define another aggregate called (for instance) `top5`, which performs the same function.  This could be more efficient if there are many distinct places for each user/type of place combination, since it can stop accumulating after the first 5, whereas the above expression will generally build a complete array of all places, and then truncate to the first 5.

*This assumes that a place has a unique earnings entry for each user/type combination.*  If a place can occur more than once, and you want to sort by `sum(money_earned)` for each place, then you need to use a subquery like in the examples below...

**Order by counts**

Ok, so the places should be ordered by how often they occur.  Here's a quick way, which uses a couple of subqueries -- add this as an expression to the select-clause of the above query:

```
(SELECT
    (array_agg(place ORDER BY cnt DESC))[1:5]
FROM
    (SELECT place, count(*) FROM earnings AS t2
     WHERE t2.user_id = earnings.user_id AND t2.type_of_place = earnings.type_of_place
     GROUP BY place) AS s (place, cnt)
) AS top5_places
```

The inner subquery called `s` evaluates to a table of each `place` for that user/type combination, and the number of times it occurs (which I've called `cnt`).  These are then fed to `array_agg` in descending order of that count.

I suspect there could be much neater (and probably more efficient) ways of writing it.  If not, then I would recommend trying to move this complicated expression into a function or aggregate, if you can...

**Histrogram of places in each hour**

We'll use a similar expression, which will return the array of counts, ordered by hour:

```
(SELECT
    array_agg(cnt ORDER BY hour DESC)
FROM
    (SELECT extract(hour FROM time), count(*) FROM earnings AS t2
     WHERE t2.user_id = earnings.user_id AND t2.type_of_place = earnings.type_of_place
     GROUP BY 1) AS s (hour, cnt)
) AS hourly_histogram
```

(Add that to the select-clause of the original query.)

Comment: Thank you @Edmund! Could you make a change for ordered the places by the number of times it appears, (`count()`) ?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, I've added a section which tries to do that.  It's a bit late in my day and it's not very nice, so I would not be surprised if there was a nicer way... :)

Comment: Thank you again @Edmund, I dunno if there is a better or elegant way of do this, let me try it, and I'll come back to you ... :)

Comment: Hi @Edmund, I found a little problem, the `(array_agg(place ORDER BY money_earned DESC))` code  returns duplicates... and using `distinct` inside doesn't solve the problem (throws an error actually...) Do you have any idea about how to solve it?

Comment: Hi again @Edmund, another question what if instead the `mode`, I want to extract a kind of histogram per user? I mean for the user 1, I would have `{2, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, ...}` where the position of the array represents the hour `(0-23)` and the number the frequency? (If you consider that this deserves that I open another question no problem, I'll do it)

Comment: Hi @nanounanue, your problem with array_agg -- that version orders by money; I thought you wanted the second version which orders by count?

Comment: Hi again! I put the version that sorts by money, just for be brief, the problem arises in both cases: Both returns the array with duplicate elements.

Comment: Hmm, did you add it to the original query?  I don't get any duplicates when I test it.  Also, I'm assuming that your data is unique on `(user_id, place, type_of_place)`.

Comment: Ok that assumption must be wrong because otherwise counts would always be 1.  I need to redo some of those expressions...!

Comment: Hi again! As I said, my database was huge, I just recently (two days ago) the query finished. Everything seems OK except for the histogram :( instead of return something like `{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 4, 5, ....}`until 24 places (24 hours) it returns something like `{1,4,4,4,5}` since the array only returns the counts it is impossible to know which hour is! (In the first array of this post each position was an hour) How I can solve this? Maybe with `generate_series`?

Comment: Hi nanounanue, you could try something like `FROM generate_series(0, 23) AS gs(i) LEFT JOIN earnings AS t2 ON gs.i = extract(hour FROM time)` in the subquery.  This should add in the missing items.

Comment: Thank you again, you are really a master of this stuff!. The query is running, I'll keep you posted :)